# DRUPAL, video module: manually upload thumbnails

Tags: drupal

I'm using the video module on Drupal and it works pretty well.

I would like to manually update thumbnails of my videos instead of automatically generate them. Is that possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks tough, there's a recent issue of someone complaining about this at http://drupal.org/node/670054 but there is a setting in the config (under automatic video thumbnailing), look at http://video.heidisoft.com/content/configuring-video-module

It'll be a lot of frustrating tweaks to get that to work, so sorry to say that no you can't manually update thumbnails using this module.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. I just realized that I wrote "update" instead of "upload" in my question. You probably got it. So you confirm, it is not possible ?

Comment: Yeah not possible with this module. You might investigate posting to youtube and then just posting an embed code in your site, I think you can pick the thumbnail at youtube.

Comment: Ok, my problem actually is that I want to build an easy back-end interface for my customer, and allow him to upload for each video a thumbnail. I thought to use 2 CCK fields (video + image), but if the order of one of the 2 lists change, the thumbnails are not anymore matching...

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you have 2 cck fields per node (video and image), and use a view to display nodes as an image linked to video, there cannot be any mismatches. Are you using views? Do you know what I mean by the view display I describe? Node displays display one node's information in each item set, it takes hackery to mix them up.

Comment: No I'm not using Views, but I'm using 2 cck fields (image + video) with unlimited items. For my customer is better to use a single project page rather then create a views and multiple nodes. So basically, if I change the order of images in the first cck field, than it is not anymore in the same order of the video cck field. Maybe I can use some jquery script to automatically drag the second cck list items ?

Comment: The more I try to help the less I feel I understand what you are doing here 8^)

If you're not using views, have you setup the customer to use a single content edit form to manage a bunch of videos and images, all attached to a single node?

Comment: hi, I answer you after many days. Sorry I've been very busy. Yes, exactly, I'm using CCK fields inside a node and not nodes with Views.